# Printing route tree in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to print a visual sitemap of my app and want to use router for that. I know current routes can be accessed via router.config like

```
this.router.config.forEach(route => {
```

but I cant find a solution to load their lazy-loaded children. When I use the Augury browser addon, I can see the whole map in no time. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think You can't load routes of lazy-loading modules...

Comment: Thats what I thought before I saw that route tree printed in Augury :-)

Comment: I think `Augury` somehow loads thous lazy-loading modules :-|

Comment: Augury is open source. Why not check their source code ? [Augury GitHub](https://github.com/rangle/augury)

Comment: I was browsing their code but did not find the relevant part, it seems like the rote tree comes as a parameter from god knows where, or I just dont know where to look.

Comment: Did you see [`parse-router.ts`](https://github.com/rangle/augury/blob/dev/src/backend/utils/parse-router.ts)?

Comment: can you add the code from your routing module?

Comment: @Gatekeeper, Augury also does not shows routes until you load lazy loaded modules, you can check by going to [route example app](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/eplnkr.html), and seeing the Router Tree, you wont find admin routes, until you log in. Hope this helps!!, Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Augury also does not shows routes until you load lazy loaded modules, you can check by going to [route example app](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/eplnkr.html), and seeing the Router Tree, you wont find admin routes.

[image]

**Having said that**, If you want to check config after lazy loaded module has been loaded, you can use below,

```
 this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd).subscribe(e => {
    console.log(this.router.config);
});
```

**[RouteConfigLoadEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteConfigLoadEnd)** Represents an event triggered when a route has been lazy loaded.

you will find a property named `_loadedConfig` in your lazy module route once the config is updated, which will have the config.

[image]

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y7qiQwf5GkIkUaSLL1Ul?p=preview)!!, look into app.component.ts, I have added above code in AppComponent constructor.

Out of curosity, I was looking into Augury code how they update Router Tree, I found below,

In [backend.ts](https://github.com/rangle/augury/blob/6b725f493b7a01768ae34e61d6577e428a4fbfc5/src/backend/backend.ts), there is a code to subscribe on `ngZone.onStable` which

> Notifies when the last onMicrotaskEmpty has run and there are no more
> microtasks

In the subscription it is checked if routes has been changed or not, if changed then routes are parsed and Router tree is updated,

snippet is as below from [parse-modules.ts](https://github.com/rangle/augury/blob/5c8fa1f97d0299f8a5db7800d96355019a323695/src/backend/utils/parse-modules.ts),

```
export const parseModulesFromRouter = (router, existingModules: NgModulesRegistry) => {
  const foundModules = [];

  const _parse = (config) => {
    config.forEach(route => {
      if (route._loadedConfig) {
        foundModules.push(route._loadedConfig.module ?
          route._loadedConfig.module.instance :
          route._loadedConfig.injector.instance);
        _parse(route._loadedConfig.routes || []);
      }
      _parse(route.children || []);
    });
  };
 ......
 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all of your "routes: Routes = []"(from each module) and create tree

it is dirty hack but works for me